# I am getting a "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Tags: python

I am having some problem. I would be very grateful if somebody please helps me out.

### This is the code :

```
def next1(n1, r1, c1, grid1):
    p_x, p_y = 0 # >>> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
    for i in range(0, n1):
        for x in range(0, n1):
            if grid1[i][x] == "p":
                p_x = i
                p_y = x
    diff_x = abs(r1-p_x)
    diff_y = abs(c1-p_y)
    if diff_x > diff_y:
        if r1-p_x > 0:
            return "UP"
        else:
            return"DOWN"
    else:
        if c1-p_y > 0:
            return"LEFT"
        else:
            return"RIGHT"


n = int(input())
r, c = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split()]
grid = []
for i in range(0, n):
    grid.append(list(input()))
grid[r][c] = "m"
print(next1(n, r, c, grid)) # >>> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

### This is the exact error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/start/bot.py", line 28, in <module>
        print(next1(n, r, c, grid))<br/>
      File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/start/bot.py", line 2, in next1
        p_x, p_y = 0
    TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Change it to `p_x = p_y = 0`.  What you have now is a multi-assignment which is trying to unpack 2 values in parallel from the constant `0`, which of course it can't do because `0` isn't an iterable.  It's expecting something like `p_x, p_y = 0, 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `px = py = 0` on that line instead (or just define those values in separate statements)

Answer (score 2):

your line `p_x, p_y = 0`  is trying to unpack from the right side of `=` operator 2 values and to assign to the left side, this will work if you have a list or a tuple, you can use:

```
p_x, p_y = 0, 0
```

in this way `p_x` and `p_y` will be equal with `0`